# Upload New Version file to chatter feed through Connect API

Tags: apex, chatter, connect-api, chatter-feed

I am trying to use "upload a new version" functionality  for files in chatter through Connect API in my VF page.I am not getting any proper solution to implement it.

Please suggest how I can do it through Connect API.

Thanks
Arabinda